# Why all of my tkinter entry widgets filled whenever I type in one of them?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to know the reason and how to solve the problem? Thank you.

```
import Tkinter

def next_screen():
    input.place_forget()
    search.place_forget()
    account()

def account():
    items = ["Username", "Password"]
    details = Tkinter.LabelFrame(main, text = "Account Details")
    details.pack(fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    for item in items:
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(details)
        frame.pack(side = "top")
        entry = Tkinter.Entry(frame, show = "*", textvariable = "StringVar")
        entry.pack(side = "right")
        label = Tkinter.Label(frame, text = item, padx = 15, pady = 15, width = 10)
        label.pack(side = "left")


main = Tkinter.Tk()
main.title("Test")
main.geometry("400x300")
input = Tkinter.Button(main, text = "Input", command = next_screen)
search = Tkinter.Button(main, text = "Search")
input.place(height = 70, width = 90, x = "55", y = "105")
search.place(height = 70, width = 90, x = "255", y = "105")
main.mainloop()
```

I am trying to learn about tkinter and try to make something out of it. Using these codes, i tried to create two buttons in the first frame and when the input is pressed, it will forget the current two buttons and show a new layer where there are two entry widgets and their labels. When I tried to run it and type in an entry widget, all the entry widgets is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does this because they all share the same value for `textvariable`

If you are just getting started, don't use `textvariable`. It's only needed for some advanced features.

And as an aside, I strongly recommend against using `place` when starting out. Learn `grid` and/or `pack`, they are much more flexible and they make it easier to make UIs that respond well to running on different systems with different resolutions and fonts.